# Why am I getting "Unhandled exception: local variable 'pwd' referenced before assignment"?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm trying to transfer a schema from my personal machine to RDS via Workbench. I've exported an SQL dump file and am trying to import it into RDS. However, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception: local variable 'pwd' referenced before assignment

Check the log for more details.
```

The log file has this:

```
14:05:01 [WRN][wb_admin_export.py:process_db:277]: Task exited with code 1
14:05:01 [ERR][       pymforms]: Unhandled exception in Python code: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export.py", line 1334, in _update_progress
    r = self.update_progress()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export.py", line 913, in update_progress
    self.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export.py", line 1323, in start
    password = self.get_mysql_password(self.bad_password_detected)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export.py", line 963, in get_mysql_password
    if pwd is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pwd' referenced before assignment
```

An earlier attempt yielded a little more detail:

```
14:00:24 [ERR][wb_admin_export.py:process_db:251]: Error from task: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'<some_numbers_I_probably_shouldn't_share!>.skybroadband.com' (using password: YES)

14:00:24 [WRN][wb_admin_export.py:process_db:277]: Task exited with code 1
14:00:24 [ERR][       pymforms]: Unhandled exception in Python code: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export.py", line 1334, in _update_progress
    r = self.update_progress()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export.py", line 913, in update_progress
    self.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export.py", line 1323, in start
    password = self.get_mysql_password(self.bad_password_detected)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export.py", line 963, in get_mysql_password
    if pwd is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pwd' referenced before assignment
14:00:43 [ERR][wb_admin_utils.py:page_activated:329]: Exception activating the page - 'Label' object has no attribute 'remove_from_parent'Error from task: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'<some_numbers_I_probably_shouldn't_share!> (using password: YES)
```

This has confused me somewhat as I'm not using Python to transfer anything - I'm using Workbench. Clearly I have a password issue but what is it exactly and how do I fix it? I'm logged into RDS and can add or remove schemas/tables etc manually so Workbench knows what the correct passwords are...

Comment: The python code is part of mysql workbench. You probably stumbled upon a bug, so you should raise this as a bug with mysql.

Answer (score 12):

For me, the error is regarding db privilege:

```sql
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'%' to database 'mydb' when doing LOCK TABLES
```

You have to uncheck the lock-tables option from the "Advanced Options" available in the top right of the data exporter in MySQL Workbench.

If you're using command to export then add `--lock-tables=FALSE` flag.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to migrate your DB Structure:

- Open workbench
- select the connection of your local DB
- On the left, in the 'navigator' panel choose 'administration'
- 'Data Export'
- select the schema you want to export
- on the right side of the window you should find a 'select box'. switch `Dump Structure and Data` to `Dump Data only`

In the same way, select `Dump Data only` when you will import it!

Honestly, I don't know exactly how it solved the error:

> 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pwd' referenced before assignment ',

but just moving the Structure without the data worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks loads for this. As I never figured out how to fix this I ditched RDS. However, I'd like to have another go so will report back!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces` and delete the workspace of the server where you are getting error, or in easy way, you can delete all folders in `sql_workspaces`

Comment: This actually sorted the error, unlike the other answer's "Dump data only". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; this error occurs when you type the wrong password. In my case, I forgot that I was working with the root user so when it asked me for the password I just had to leave the input blank and hit the continue button.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem: answers with `--lock-tables=FALSE` and 'Dump Data only' didn't help in my case.

Workbench gave alert

> Unhandled exception: local variable 'pwd' referenced before assignment';

But log tell me 'Access denied for user': [workbench error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn6oy.png)

Granting all privileges to user solved my problem:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while exporting the database, I had to create another user whose host is limited to my pc ip where workbench is installed instead of the %.